# How to write Java code into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

I am struggling to convert Java code into javascript. For that, for example, I am converting **public static int primesolution** into **function primesolution**. I do not have much idea whether I am on the right track of converting it. I am stuck with  **public static void main(String[] args)**. How to convert this function into Javascript. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class EvaluateDivisors {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            long a = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            long b = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

            if (a <= 1 || b <= a) {
                error("Error: must have 1 < A < B");
            }
            if (k <= 0 || k % 2 == 0) {
                error("Error: K must be a positive odd number");
            }
            System.out.println(solution(a, b, k));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            error("Usage: EvaluateDivisors A B K");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            error("Error: arguments must be integers");
        }
    }


    private static int solution(long a, long b, int k) {


        if (prime(k)) {
            return primeSolution(a, b, k);
        }
        int result = 0;

         for (long n = (long) Math.sqrt(a); n*n <= b; n++) {

           int divisors = 3;


            for (long m = 2; m < n && divisors <= k; m++) {
                if (n*n % m == 0) {
                    divisors += 2;
                }
            }
            if (divisors == k) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


      private static int primeSolution(long a, long b, int k) {
        int result = 0;


        int n = 2;
        while (Math.pow(n, k - 1) < a) {
            n++;
        }
        while (Math.pow(n, k - 1) <= b) {
            if (prime(n++)) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    private static boolean prime(int n) {

        for (int m = 2; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m++) {
            if (n % m == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static void error(String message) {
        System.err.println(message);
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

**My converted code in JavaScript**

```
function EvaluateDivisors {

    function main(String[] args) {
        try {
            long a = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            long b = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

            if (a <= 1 || b <= a) {
                error("Error: must have 1 < A < B");
            }
            if (k <= 0 || k % 2 == 0) {
                error("Error: K must be a positive odd number");
            }
            System.out.println(solution(a, b, k));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            error("Usage: EvaluateDivisors A B K");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            error("Error: arguments must be integers");
        }
    }


    function solution(long a, long b, int k) {

        if (prime(k)) {
            return primeSolution(a, b, k);
        }
        int result = 0;

        for (long n = (long) Math.sqrt(a); n*n <= b; n++) {

            int divisors = 3;

            for (long m = 2; m < n && divisors <= k; m++) {
                if (n*n % m == 0) {
                    divisors += 2;
                }
            }
            if (divisors == k) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function primeSolution(long a, long b, int k) {
      int result = 0;

       int n = 2;
      while (Math.pow(n, k - 1) < a) {
          n++;
      }
      while (Math.pow(n, k - 1) <= b) {
          if (prime(n++)) {
              result++;
          }
      }
      return result;
  }


        function prime(int n) {
        for (int m = 2; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m++) {
            if (n % m == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function error(String message) {
        console.log(message);
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event listener for document load (that will execute its content after loading html):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // Your main() code here
});

or change it to classic function with parameters like this:

function mainFunction(yourVar)
```

then, JS is dynamically typed language, so you have to use universal var istead of int, long, string or whatever.

Then you can place other functions side by side with functions above, so your final javascript code will look like this:

```
// Use function like this:
// function yourFunction(parameter1, parameter2, ...) {
// or use document DOMContentLoaded event listener:
function yourFunction(a, b, k) {
    try {
        if (a <= 1 || b <= a) {
            error("Error: must have 1 < A < B");
        }
        if (k <= 0 || k % 2 == 0) {
            error("Error: K must be a positive odd number");
        }
        console.log(solution(a, b, k));
    } catch(e) {
        error("Usage: EvaluateDivisors A B K");
    }
};

function solution(a, b, k) {  
    if (prime(k)) {
        return primeSolution(a, b, k);
    }
    var result = 0;

    for (var n = Math.sqrt(a); n * n <= b; n++) {

        var divisors = 3;

        for (var m = 2; m < n && divisors <= k; m++) {
            if (n * n % m == 0) {
                divisors += 2;
            }
        }
        if (divisors == k) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function primeSolution(a, b, k) {
    var result = 0;

    var n = 2;
    while (Math.pow(n, k - 1) < a) {
        n++;
    }
    while (Math.pow(n, k - 1) <= b) {
        if (prime(n++)) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


function prime(n) {
    for (var m = 2; m <= Math.sqrt(n); m++) {
        if (n % m == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function error(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

I can recommend you using JavaScript validator: http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Then for debugging your browsers console (on windows you can open it in almost any browser using F12)

And to search for help on w3schools, its awesome source for help:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/